# Unable to get length of Firebase Objects

Tags: json, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am currently using AngularFire, and trying to get the length of objects in my database.

In my Firebase, the structure looks like

```
popping-fire-5575
  celio
   -JgaQt-tNq-gRVIVZdCD
     artist:  
     track:  
   -JgaQuBoYk9VX3pWylx3
     artist: 
     track: 
   -JgaQuf_pyBFJ7EA1Fo_
     artist: 
     track:
```

In my controller,

```
var profileObject = FirebaseDemo.getBroadcast($routeParams.param);
var twotwo = profileObject.$asObject();
twotwo.$bindTo($scope, 'data');
```

When I console log the variable 'twotwo',
I get in return

```
Object
$$conf: Object
$id: "celio"
$priority: null
-JgaQt-tNq-gRVIVZdCD: Object
-JgaQuBoYk9VX3pWylx3: Object
-JgaQuf_pyBFJ7EA1Fo_: Object
__proto__: Object
```

However, I have tried all different ways to get the length, but I am not able to get to succeed.  Could someone give me some directions or tips?

Comment: Unrelated to my answer below: I get the impression that your question is based on some tutorial or class. If that is the case, can you point me to the tutorial/class? I'd like to read a bit more about it, since you're not the first person to get stuck with the assignment and maybe we can do something to help the people with the assignment more structurally.

Comment: Objects don't have a length. Arrays do. Also, [this guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html) is probably the best one to start with, since it explains basic fundamentals of AngularFire, like objects and arrays. I would also like to know who is putting out this tutorial. It baffles me as to why official documentation is such a last resort, and why so many people struggling with fundamentals like JavaScript objects not having a .length attribute are so often attempting to conquer Angular and Firebase all on day one.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase loads (and synchronizes) you data asynchronously, so by the time your `console.log` statement runs it is probably still busy loading the data.

Luckily AngularFire has a way to notify and run your code when the initial loading of data has completed:

```
var twotwo = profileObject.$asArray();
twotwo.$loaded().then(function(data) {
    console.log('Initial data loaded', data.length);
});
```

The two main changes from your code:

1. Use `$asArray()` instead of `$asObject()`, since your data structure is an array
2. Listen for the `$loaded` "event" and respond to that

Note that AngularFire will already notify AngularJS of any changes to the data, so you won't have to respond to `$loaded` if you just bind the data to the `$scope` and show it in your view.