# Iterating through a firebase collection

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a collection of items that are stored in firebase, the item object have two properties, name and selected.
I have all the items printed out to the view, and they each have a checkbox that changes the property of selected to true.
I also has a button at the bottom that has a function binded to it, deleteSelected().

My thought was to iterate through the firebase objects somehow, and then check if they have the property of selected=true, and then delete the items. I tried using the $asObject() function on the firebase object, but got this error.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
 at new <anonymous> (controllers.js:17)
 at invoke (angular.js:3374)
 at Object.instantiate (angular.js:3386)
 at $get (angular.js:5902)
 at angular.js:5400
 at forEach (angular.js:220)
 at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:5387)
 at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:4911)
 at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:4914)
 at publicLinkFn (angular.js:4819)
```

How can I iterate through firebase objects? or is there a much easier way of tackling this problem?

Here is the code if you wanna have a look: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HCfEg1SQx9CpgmAdafGF)

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://inkopslista.firebaseio.com/items");
//creates a firebase object that takes a reference to the firebase URL
var items = $firebase(firebaseRef);

$scope.items = items;
```

This is the function that is binded to a button with ng-click.

```
$scope.deleteSelected = function(){

    for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++){

        if(items[i].selected === true){
            console.log(items[i]);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Please include the minimum code that produces the problem you have in the question itself. Just pointing to a plunker is not enough, especially if that plunkr gives all kinds of other errors when I try to run it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok will do that, thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to my answer below: I get the impression that your question is based on some tutorial or class. If that is the case, can you point me to the tutorial/class? I'd like to read a bit more about it, since you're not the first person to get stuck with the assignment and maybe we can do something to help the people with the assignment more structurally.

Comment: I'm not currently following a tutorial, but I'm really new to angular, and I have watched some videos on egghead.io.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array-like structure in your Firebase, you should call `$asArray` and not `$asObject`. AngularFire's `FirebaseArray` class (which is what `$asArray` returns) does a lot of work behind the scenes to ensure that Firebase's ordered collections map nicely into a JavaScript array (which is what AngularJS expects).

Modified from your plunker:

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://your.firebaseio.com/items");

//creates a firebase object that takes a reference to the firebase URL
var items = $firebase(firebaseRef);

$scope.items = items.$asArray();

$scope.items.$loaded().then(function(array) {
    console.log('Initial items received from Firebase', array.length);
});
```

Also see: [Unable to get length of Firebase Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151487/unable-to-get-length-of-firebase-objects/28153387#28153387)

## Update

You seem to be using a really old version of Firebase and AngularFire. The handling of array-like structures was considerably improved in version 0.8. If you don't upgrade, you'll end up reproducing a lot of the code that was introduced in recent versions.

To give you some idea, I quickly put your controller and view into a jsbin and made it work with the most recent versions of AngularJS, Firebase and AngularFire.

```
.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$firebase", "$filter" , function($scope, $firebase, $filter){
    var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://inkopslista.firebaseio.com/items");
    var items = $firebase(firebaseRef);
    $scope.items = items.$asArray();

    $scope.addItem = function(item){
        if(item === undefined){
            return null;
        }else{
            item.selected = false;
            $scope.items.$add(item);
        }    
        $scope.newItem = null;
    };


    $scope.deleteItem = function(id){
        $scope.items.$remove(id);
    };

    $scope.deleteSelected = function(){
        $scope.items.forEach(function(item) {
            if (item.selected) {
                $scope.items.$remove(item);
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

The jsbin: http://jsbin.com/varoka/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I tried your code, but I'm still getting the same error, wierdly enough.

Comment: YIKES. I just now checked the versions in your plunker and see that you're using AngularFire 0.7. When you make the Plunker work, also take some time to update it to a more recent version. `$asArray()` was introduced in AngularFire 0.8 over half a year ago. If you're following a tutorial now, there is no reason to stick to that old a version.

Comment: Yeah.. Now it works! Thanks for taking the time to help me. I guess this answer is right though since it answers my question.